# Offline Google Maps stored in my app HTML/CSS/JQuery

Tags: android, maps

I searched and searched, but i cant find out is it possible to use offline google maps / OpenStreetMaps in my Adroid application (which would be 100% offline)...
Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (or better, not allowed) with Google Maps.
For OpenStreetMaps look [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Getting_Data). Maybe not trivial, but possible and allowed.